# How to add ViewController on top of tabBarViewcontroller using storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

In my application i want to add a viewcontroller with nib on top of tabbarviewcontroller using storyboard.
for eg; when the application launch for first time i want to show that view controller for once and after that when ever user start the application it should show the tabbarviewcontroller. and not the viewcontroller.

following is my code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused with how you described what you want.  There are a couple of ways to do what you want and depending on how you want things to flow.

Storyboard
If you stay in the storyboard, you can add a UIViewController - in front of your tabbar (to the left of) controller.  Basically, add a UIViewController and move the start arrow to it.  then create a segue from it to your tabbar controller.  You can bring in the tabbar controller via a push segue or even as a modal segue if you want.

You would have to move your xib file into the storyboard. 
It would flow like this:  UIViewController -> UITabbarController -> Rest of your app.
In this model, the first view controller would always be available on launch.

Another strategy - trying to keep things simple is to use the first view controller attached to the tabbar.  It would align with the left most tab.
That view controller gets instantiated and put on screen by the tabbar controller first under normal conditions.  You can add code in that UIViewController in the ViewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear methods to instantiate and put up the modal view using either a storyboard or a nib file.

Finally, the last way I can think of would be to load the nib file from your app delegate  then display your tabbar from the storybook as a modal.  I think this approach is the least desirable, but doable.

hope that helps. good luck.